# How do I output the contents of a variable in grid form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I have the following code for my Ruby on Rails project, which outputs a list of users on a page:

```
<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>`
```

The result is a long list of users on the page.

My question is: How can I manipulate `@users` so that I can output its content in grid form (e.g., a row of 5 users and then next row and then next and so on) on the page? Thanks.

Comment: you should look into some pagination solutions, like https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: @Subash I think OP wants to display them in the same page with a different layout (grid instead of list)

Comment: I already have pagination going. I just prefer a grid to a vertical list.

Comment: Why don't you just print each in a DIV and use CSS for the positioning? A lot better if you support multiple devices.

Comment: @bo-oz I am using RoR and Bootstrap, both of which provide methods for doing these types of things.

Comment: Bootstrap = css, why not use that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
      <% users.in_groups_of(5) do |group| %>
        <% group.compact.each do |user| %>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
             <%= image_tag (user.file_url), class: "img-sz" %>
               <h4><%= link_to user.title, user %></h4>
             <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) , remote: true, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
              <%= link_to "delete", user,remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %></br></br>
           </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %> 
</div>
```

This is example code change the name of attributes according to your structure . This will help you in solving your problem .

Comment: This is totally useless, what is different from looping over the result set directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple example and you can customise into a nicer table.
The basic idea is to group the array of users in subarrays of n elements, lets say 5.

```
<% @users.each_slice(5).each do |row| %>
  <p><% row.each do |user| %>
      <%= user.name %> | 
    <% end %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does it generate different output than `@users.each`?

Comment: As soon as `@users.size > 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was close but I went with the answer provided by @Bodharth because it directly helped me since I am using Bootstrap as well as images for my user profiles.